# Custom slide out div jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a few more issues with a script. I am trying to achieve a responsive slide out div script for a "meet the team" page. The way I see it working is that when the persons image is clicked, it slides out their bio. I am running into a few issues though.

1) Script works fine until you click the 3rd or 4th image in the row:

- When the 3rd image is clicked, it slides out the div fine, but creates a blank space on the next row (i'm assuming it is pushing the image onto a new line but also adding a margin...)
- When the 4th image is clicked, it is creating the bio outside of the container. The only way I can see a fix for this would be to have it slide the opposite way for every 4th item in a row. I can add a counter class to the divs dynamically using my CMS, just not sure how to reference this in the javascript.

2) I'm unsure how to make it work responsively. I am dropping the container from 1/4 to 1/2 on tablet and mobile. So I need to basically double the margin and size of the bio container. How can I declare this in the script?

Many thanks in advance for any help. Credit to Trim Kadrui who helped me with the script so far.

JS Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QrfzA/21/

Script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.team-photo').click(function() {
        var teamBio = $(this).next();
        var nextBlock = $(this).parent().next();
        if(teamBio.width() > 0){
            teamBio.animate({width: 0, opacity: 0});
            nextBlock.animate({marginLeft: '0%'});
        }
        else {
            teamBio.css("display", "inline-block");
            teamBio.animate({width: '100%', opacity: 100});
            nextBlock.animate({marginLeft: '25%'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: CSS hover effect can also apply

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.team-photo').click(function() {
   var teamBio = $(this).next();
   var nextBlock = $(this).parent().next();
   if(teamBio.width() > 0){
    nextBlock.css("clear", "none");
    teamBio.animate({width: 0, opacity: 0});
    nextBlock.animate({marginLeft: '0%'});
   }
   else {
    teamBio.css("display", "inline-block");
    teamBio.animate({width: '100%', opacity: 100});
    if(nextBlock.position().left>10) {
        nextBlock.animate({marginLeft: '25%'});
        if(!nextBlock.next().length || nextBlock.next().position().left<10) {
            nextBlock.animate({marginLeft: '0'});
            nextBlock.css("clear", "both");
        }
    }
}
});
});
```

`if(nextBlock.position().left>10)` does the trick,basically it checks if the there are more than 10 pixels to the left of the `nextBlock`  and then applies the margin left property.

I've checked to see if `nextBlock.position().left` is greater than `10`,you can set it to suite your needs.

**EDIT:** `nextBlock.next().position().left<10` was also needed to be checked in case,the image is last but one in that line. CSS property `clear:both` was used to send the nextblock to the new line instead of using a margin.

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrfzA/24/).

Comment: Hi phpcoderx, thanks for this although it doesn't seem to have changed anything? Still having the same issues. http://jsfiddle.net/QrfzA/22/

Comment: @kala233 Didn't check the problem when clicking the 3rd image,edited my answer,this should work.